# Python single mkdirs makes two directories with 1 min time interval

Tags: python, strftime

I am seeing a strange issue where the same mkdirs command with a timestamp affixed directory name makes two directories for another user but a single one for me.

We are both running the same python scripts on the same Linux machine (of course logging in remotely to the machine from our individual PCs via VPN). The two directories created for him have just a 1 minute time difference. The first directory is always empty and the second one is filled with the data. What could be the cause of this and how do I fix it?

```py
outdir = os.getcwd() + "/output/" + file + "." + now.strftime("%m.%d.%Y.%H.%M") + "/"

if not os.path.exists(outdir):
    os.makedirs(outdir)
```

Running the script once creates ./output/file.09.08.2021.19.35 and ./output/file.09.08.2021.19.36. The two directories are created for him no matter when the script is run and never for me.

Comment: Can you show the code around that part? Maybe that is run in a loop? Or the function is being called twice?

Comment: Also, can you see what command the script is called with for each of you?

Comment: He runs the exact same python command from the Linux terminal that I do. This piece of code is in a configuration script called myconfig.py. This configuration script is then called by my main python script using 'import myconfig'.

Comment: So we both run 'python ./scripts/process_files.py' from the terminal. Both are running bash shell. The python script has a couple of command line input prompts from the user before proceeding to process data. Let me know what other info I can provide.

Comment: Write a debug message to the console or a logfile, to see if the code is run twice. If it is, add more debug messages, until you find the bug.

Comment: If there is 1 minute delay, it's also maybe because your program tried more often but you're test of an existing folder stopped it (you could try to know if there are more than these 2 calls). As already precised above, please show us (or at least check) how this code is called, the problem comes probably from this